# Can i use my old C++ code(Game Directx based) for both ios and android?

Tags: android, c++, ios

1. I developed games for windows using directx .
2. Is their any way to use these codes

Thanks

Comment: Please add more info to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ok
2. No.

DirectX is a Windows-only API.
Mac and iOS are built on a foundation of OpenGL. I believe Android also supports OpenGL. Windows supports OpenGL as well.

If you want to write cross-platform 3D games you should use OpenGL, not a single-platform API like DirectX.

You can write games in C++ for iOS. The development environment supports C, C++, Objective C, and Java. However, the OS frameworks are written in Objective C and you will need to learn some Objective C in order to interface with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, No.

Detailed answer, NOOOOOOHH!